# Postgres. Проверка наличия у пользователя привилегии на ВСЕ последовательности схемы

Tags: postgresql

Я хочу дать пользователю привилегии на все последовательности схемы. Например, так:

```
grant usage, select on all SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA test to anyuser
```

или даже так:

```
grant all on all SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA test to anyuser
```

Каким запросом можно потом получить информацию о наличии у пользователя определенных или ВСЕХ прав на ВСЕ последовательности схемы?